# How to have an annotation only in one pod of a given deployment?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-deployment

Imagine you have a Kubernetes deployment in a cluster with autoscaling capabilities.

I want to make sure that only of the pods from this deployment contains a specific annotation.

It could be for example the first running pod, and when it stops working this annotation would be replicated to a different pod.

Comment: You can't: every pod created by a deployment is identical (except for its name) and the pods never change after they're created.  What's the larger problem you're trying to solve with this annotation?

Comment: I am deploying the Kubernetes autoscaler in my cluster, and I want to guarantee that when a node is removed due to scale down, that node won't be removed if it contains the last replicas of a given deployment. I could use the annotation safe-to-evict: false, but this would make the scale down not happen at all.

Comment: Have you looked at https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/configure-pdb/?

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to prevent downtime while some nodes are going down annotations is probably not the best way. You can use a combination of some of these.

- [Pod Topology Spread Constraints](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-topology-spread-constraints/). For example, make sure there is always a pod running in one of the availability zones. Or on a node that never goes down.
- [Pod Disruption Budget](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/configure-pdb/) (mentioned in the comments above). For example, make sure that you always have a minimum set of unavailable pods. For example, don't allow the cluster autoscaler to drain the node unless another pod is up somewhere else.

✌️